# Equality of polynomials and their equivalent fraction forms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A polynomial of the form $\frac{p(t)\cdot (x+1)}{(x+1)}$ is obviously equal to $p(t)$ because the binomials cancel out, where $p(t)$ is just any arbitrary polynomial. But the first form is undefined for $x=-1$, while the second form is defined for that value.

Is there some sort of idea that deals with this sort of contradiction, it just seems like there is more to this story, sorry if this doesn't seem like a very clear question I'm not very well versed in math but this sort of thing has been bothering me, the two functions should be equal but they aren't for at least one point. The same sort of thing happens for $e^{ln(x)}$ which is equal to x, but the first form is not defined for $x=0$, because $ln(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Here you will find a tutorial about Mathjax (to write mathematical expressions)
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about the notion of *functions* being nonequal. In your first example, $\frac{x+1}{x+1}$ is shorthand for the function $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x+1}$. Now, as you've pointed out, it is undefined for $x=-1$, that is, $-1$ is not in the domain of $f$. Thus, $f:\mathbb{R}-\{-1\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

By way of comparison, the polynomial $x$ is shorthand for the function $g$, where $g(x) = x$. Since this is defined everywhere, $g: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

As you might suspect, we define two functions to be equal if and only if

- their domains are equal, and
- their effects are equal.

That is why $f$ and $g$ are not equal functions; their domains are not the same. However, where their domains agree, their effects are equal.